# Reactjs , MaterialUI calendar days's names

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

How to change name of the day in week. I could not find anything in documentation neither google.

[image: MaterialUI calendar]

I have not try anything as I said I could not find any info about it.

Comment: There is a [dayOfWeekFormatter](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props) prop

Comment: It did not work for me . I have tried it already.Nothing changed.

Comment: Could you add the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.